# Undefined name 'mounted'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using provider for the state management on Flutter. I'm making async await function and have warning that Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps. So I tried to put 'if(!mounted)' code and I got warning that Undefined name 'mounted'.

How can I fix this problem? Thank you!

Provider codes

```
signIn(BuildContext context) async{
    try {
      final navigator = Navigator.of(context);
      !isSignupValid ? isSignupValid = true : null;
      await authentication.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: userEmail.trim(), password: userPassword.trim()
      );
      navigator.pop();
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (errorCode) {
      isSignupValid = false;
      print('isSignupValid : $isSignupValid');
      print('SignIn FirebaseAuthException : $errorCode');
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        returnSnackBar(context, errorCode)
      );
    }
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 0));
    if (!mounted) return;
    context.watch<ProfileData>().profileImage = null;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: Where is this mounted variable defined? From where does it get its value?

Comment: I guess it's not defined. How can I define the mounted variable?

Comment: `bool mounted = false;`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `mounted` property is only available in a `StatefulWidget`. If you are not in a stateful widget you have no way of knowing whether the context you are using still references the state of a widget which is still in the widget tree.

I'm not sure exactly what you do. You can either change your widget to a `StatefulWidget` or simply do a `final profileData = context.read<ProfileData>()` at the beginning of you method, and never access `context` after your first `async` call.

Answer (score 3):

Since Flutter version [3.7.0](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/release-notes-3.7.0) `BuildContext` now has a [mounted](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/mounted.html) property. Here's the PR https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/111619.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether the widget is mounted in a **StatelessWidget**, you can try using a **GlobalKey** to obtain a reference to the widget and then check its mounted property:

```
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final _globalKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      key: _globalKey,
      child: Text('Hello, world!'),
    );
  }

  bool get isMounted => _globalKey.currentState != null && _globalKey.currentState!.mounted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run these two lines in the terminal

```
$ flutter channel stable
$ flutter upgrade
```

Flutter version 3.7.0 BuildContext now has a mounted property. [Check this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/111619)